# How can I bind a javascript dialog using Knockout?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've got a list of data in an observableArray and I want to show it in a javascript dialog window (I'm using jQuery.blockUI if it matters). Unfortunately the dialog seems to come unbound after the page is loaded. The dialog initializes correctly (the data is displayed), but it isn't updating with changes.

There are no Javascript errors and I've moved the binding to after the dialog is generated and added to the document (no effect). I've also tried calling ko.applyBinding on the main div that makes up the dialog but that, for some reason, causes part of the main page to hide (the DOM is there, but they are hidden).

**EDIT:** I've created a project on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yL6ds/3/) that reproduces the problem. The main culprit seems to be wrapping the content of the dialog in a div. If I show the content directly it seems to work (of course I can't do that, the wrappers provide a common style for our dialogs).

I'm recovering from the flu and could easily be missing something obvious, but I've been trying all day and nothing is coming to me. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post an example jsfiddle?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce it in jsFiddle, but I was able to determine that it has something to do with the dialog (though probably something I'm doing and not blockUI). I'll report back when I have a better answer to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the dialog does not exist in the DOM (despite your calling `$(document).append()`. You cannot append a div as a child of the document itself).  Instead, append the dialog to the body and hide it.

```
$dlg = $('<div></div>').hide();
$('body').append($dlg);
```

**Works here:** http://jsfiddle.net/yL6ds/4/

Comment: D'OH! Just a stupid mistake :). Thanks. Wasted most of 8 hours on this, grrr. The dialog code has been working in production for over a year (first time with Knockout) and I never thought to even look at it (funny that I reproduced it in jsFiddle).